# Two Power Series Identify on an Open interval not Containing Zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I searched a lot for a convincing answer for this question but failed to find one (That is formally complete).

I wonder if the following claim is true, and if so, for a formal proof.

Claim:

Let there be two power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nx^n$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_nx^n$ with radii of convergence $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively s.t $R_2\ge R_1>0$. Suppose that for some $R_1>b>a>0\;\;\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nx^n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_nx^n\;\;\forall x\in(a,b)$. Then: $a_n=b_n\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know exactly how to prove a similar theorem, when the two power series identify on an open interval **containing zero**, one can calculate the derivatives at zero and thus obtaining the desired equality. However, I couldn't proof this case when **zero is not contained by the interval**. This is exactly the crucial part to which I can't find an appropriate solution.

I would very much appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The Identity Principle. The power series expansions based at $0$ indeed are not optimal to help you prove what you want...

Comment: Don’t you have any more letters than $a$ and $b$? It’s annoying and inconsistent to use $a_i$ and $b_i$ for coefficients of series, but $a$ and $b$ for the endpoints of a segment. ( apologies for the crankiness )

Comment: @Lubin You are totally correct, duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion can be proved by applying complex analysis. Let $$f(z) =\sum a_nz^n,\quad g(z)=\sum b_nz^n,\quad |z|<R_1$$ By assumption $f(x)=g(x)$ for $a<x<b,$ hence $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $|z|<R_1.$ Therefore the  MacLaurin coefficients of $f$ and $g$ coincide.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. However, I do wonder what is the formal justification for your claim (As it is quite similar to the one I wish to prove, of course under the assumption zero is not contained by the interval). Is there a theorem or a lemma that I'm missing? I'd very much appreciate it if you could refer me to a relevant source containing the proof for this or alternatively sketch the outlines of a proof.

Comment: @G.Bar I have based on the property that the zeros of analytic functions are isolated in an open  domain of holomorphy say $\Omega$, and can accumulate only at the boundary of $\Omega$.   The proof of this theorem is pretty straightforward and based on the fact that  if a nonzero function $f$ vanishes at $z_0$ then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^n g(z),$ and $g$ does not vanish in a neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0.$ Hence $f(z)$ does not vanish on $U\setminus\{z_0\}.$ Two functions which are equal on a subset of $\Omega,$ which has an accumulation point in $\Omega$ are equal, by considering their difference.